# What are some good texts to study the philosophy of self-reference?

Tags: logic, reference-request

I was curious if anyone could recommend a good text to get a foothold on some the main issues regarding self-reference. I am interested in the mathematical and philosophy of language aspects of self-reference. I appreciate any advice. Thanks.

Comment: In all seriousness, a good prologue to any study in the philosophy of logic and language would be Lewis Carroll's *Alice in Wonderland* and *Through the Looking Glass*. It only takes an afternoon or two to read them start to finish.

Answer (score 4):

If you haven't already looked at Thomas Bolander's Stanford Encyclopedia article on [Self-Reference](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/self-reference/), I can certainly recommend it and its excellent bibliography.  As a general collection of essays on the problems of Liar phenomena and their strengthenings in language, I would also endorse J. C. Beall's [Revenge of the Liar: New essays on the paradox](http://books.google.co.uk/books/about/Revenge_of_the_Liar.html?id=S50WAQAAMAAJ&redir_esc=y), and I myself am currently reading Raymond Smullyan's [Diagonalization and self-reference](http://philpapers.org/rec/SMUDAS), which is a technical but awesome book looking at the mathematical issues around fixed points, recursion and incompleteness.

Comment: +1, but just wondering -- no Hofstadter? :)

Comment: Nope. No Hofstadter. =P

Comment: ("Godel, Escher, Bach" is a very fun and masterfully written book, but Hofstadter is particularly focused on intentionality, where this is kind of an aside to the current state of the self-reference literature.)

Answer (score 1):

Lucy O'Brien's "Self-Knowing Agents" is a good book about self-reference (more for the phil of lang side). Gareth Evan's work might also be of interest to you, for example "The Varieties of Reference".